# Como gerar imagem temporária para ambiente de desenvolvimento?

Tags: php, html

Algum tempo atrás encontrei um post que mostrava como gerar imagens temporárias, uma imagem com fundo cinza e uma marcação de fundo contendo as dimensões da mesma. Essa imagem é gerada automaticamente, com dimensões determinadas via passagem de parâmetro get, ou seja, não ficava salva em disco, servia somente para termos uma previa de como o layout ficaria.

Entretanto, perdi este post e não consigo localizar nada que fale sobre o recurso. Alguma orientação de como posso utilizar este recurso? Documentação, etc?

Comment: Você está falando de "placeholder" para imagem? Vejo isso em prototipações rápidas

Comment: Mais ou menos, era de fato uma imagem, mas invés de uma "figura" havia uma marcação com as dimensões da imagem. A mesma era gerada via chamada de uma URL. Editei o post para melhor esclarecimento da minha dúvida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que está se referindo ao https://placeholder.com/, nele você pode gerar imagens "com fundo cinza e uma marcação de fundo contendo as dimensões da mesma".

Por exemplo:

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```

Se quiser, pode até mudar a cor, além do tamanho:

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x500/d00254/f565845">
```

---

Comment: Esse mesmo. Obrigado.